# Issues inheriting Vaadin's Lumo theme properties

Tags: themes, vaadin

I have downloaded the [Business App](https://labs.vaadin.com/business-tabs/) and wanted to play around with styling. I noticed that, for instance, the app-bar.css is doing:

```
.app-bar {
  background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);
  box-shadow: var(--lumo-box-shadow-s);
...
```

Now, I understand that `--lumo-base-color` is taken from `frontend/styles/lumo.css`. However, I did change all the colors for `[theme~="dark"]`, I redeployed the app and `.app-bar` fails to pick the new Lumo values. Am I doing something wrong? If I put explicit values in `app-bar.css`, they get applied without problems. Using Vaadin 14.

Comment: Do you actually have frontend/styles/lumo.css? I haven't seen that before. Where did you change all the colors for [theme~="dark"]? Do you mean .tab-bar instead? At least in the demo you linked to, that’s the visible element.

Comment: Absolutely. As mentioned, I did change colors in frontend/styles/lumo.css without effect.

Comment: So, did the lumo.css file come already with Business App? Or do you mean frontend/styles/styles.css, or some file under frontend/styles/lumo folder?